# complex mysql query runs out of memory

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a view from multiple tables and I'm by no stretch competent with mysql. I think the query works but the tables are large and the temp table runs out of memory so I am hoping someone has another approach to accomplish this

table inventory_dated (315782 rows)

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Device_Name   | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Chassis_Name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FPC           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| PIC           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| XCVR          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Part_Name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Version       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Part_Number   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Serial_Number | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Model_Number  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Description   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Install_Date  | timestamp    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| maxdate       | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
+----+----------------------------+--------------+-----+-----+------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | Device_Name                | Chassis_Name | FPC | PIC | XCVR | Part_Name | Version | Part_Number | Serial_Number | Model_Number | Description | Install_Date        | maxdate             |
+----+----------------------------+--------------+-----+-----+------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | abc.ga.atlanta             |              |     |     |      | Chassis   |         |             | 1234          |              | model       | 2012-03-29 21:00:00 | 2016-04-25 09:35:00 |
+----+----------------------------+--------------+-----+-----+------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

table calendar_month (469 rows)

```
+------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date_month | date | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+------------+
| date_month |
+------------+
| 2011-01-01 |
+------------+
```

table device_list (6715 rows)

```
 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(25)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Device_Name | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| Platform    | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Network     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Division    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Market      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
+------+----------------------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| ID   | Device_Name                | Platform | Network | Division | Market  |
+------+----------------------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| 7086 | abc.ga.atlanta             | platform | net1    | div1     | market1 |
+------+----------------------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

My query runs out or memory even though there is over 18GB in tmp available

```
SELECT
    inventory_dated.Device_Name,
    inventory_dated.Chassis_Name,
    inventory_dated.FPC,
    inventory_dated.PIC,
    inventory_dated.XCVR,
    inventory_dated.Part_Name,
    inventory_dated.Version,
    inventory_dated.Part_Number,
    inventory_dated.Serial_Number,
    inventory_dated.Model_Number,
    inventory_dated.Description,
    calendar_month.date_month,
    device_list.Platform,
    device_list.Network,
    device_list.Division,
    device_list.Market
FROM inventory_dated 
JOIN calendar_month
INNER JOIN device_list ON inventory_dated.Device_Name = device_list.Device_Name
where (`calendar_month`.`date_month` between date_format(`inventory_dated`.`Install_Date`,'%Y-%m-01') and coalesce(`inventory_dated`.`maxdate`,cast(now() as datetime))) 
order by `calendar_month`.`date_month`
```

What I am trying to accomplish is domain padding or dense data in which I can combine the inventory_dated table with the calendar_month table to return a record for each month between and including install_date and max_date for every record in inventory_dated as well as grab corresponding data from device_list for the same device. The query consumes all tmp memory and dies with

```
[Err] 126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_4125_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

I have essentially the same query working just fine on smaller tables. Hoping this makes sense and someone can help optimize the query
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference but the `WHERE` clause should actually be the `ON` clause for the first `JOIN`.

Comment: What happens if you take `calendar_month` out of the query, does it perform well then?

Comment: Don't use `date_format(Install_Date, ...)`, just use `DATE(Install_Date)`.

Comment: I tried using DATE()with no better result. the reason i used date format was to bound the date entry to the first of the month to match the data in calendar_month. otherwise it skips months

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the `-01`. in the format. That makes sense (I've done similar things).

Comment: I beleive the issue is that the query doesnt limit by the number of months before it tries to build the data set so it is trying to create 148M records instead of 9M records. How can the query be rewritten to first reduce the months which match in the calendar table but are prior to today?